# Ngx-Charts show all x axis values but alternate x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ngx-charts

I am currently working on ngx charts, for examples i have 12 x-axis every values need to be plotted in graph, but only alternate x-axis label need to be displayed.

**html code**

```
<ngx-charts-area-chart  [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [legend]="legend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxis]="xAxis" [yAxis]="yAxis"
 [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [results]="multi" (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-area-chart>
```

data.ts

```
var multi = [ {
"name": "Belarus",
"series": [
  {
    "value": 5776,
    "name": "Jan 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 4299,
    "name": "Feb 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 3995,
    "name": "Mar 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 6597,
    "name": "Apr 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 4954,
    "name": "May 19"
  },
  {
    "name": "June 19",
    "value": 3865
  },
  {
    "name": "July 19",
    "value": 2349
  },
  {
    "name": "Aug 19",
    "value": 6910
  },
  {
    "name": "Sept 19",
    "value": 6224
  },
  {
    "name": "Oct 19",
    "value": 4161
  },
  {
    "name": "Nov 19",
    "value": 4825
  },
  {
    "name": "Dec 19",
    "value": 3835
  }
]},{
"name": "Croatia",
"series": [
  {
    "value": 2576,
    "name": "Jan 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 5427,
    "name": "Feb 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 3097,
    "name": "Mar 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 4385,
    "name": "Apr 19"
  },
  {
    "value": 4849,
    "name": "May 19"
  },
  {
    "name": "June 19",
    "value": 2867
  },
  {
    "name": "July 19",
    "value": 6241
  },
  {
    "name": "Aug 19",
    "value": 6517
  },
  {
    "name": "Sept 19",
    "value": 3808
  },
  {
    "name": "Oct 19",
    "value": 2068
  },
  {
    "name": "Nov 19",
    "value": 5121
  },
  {
    "name": "Dec 19",
    "value": 3876
  }
]}]
```

In the above data set in x-axis I need to plot all values in the graph but only alternate labels need to displayed. This need to be applied for all types of ngx charts.